# Count the number of lines in a column where some cells have multiple lines

Tags: google-sheets

How to count the number of lines when some cells in a column contain multiple lines? Example:

```
+----------------------+
| text                 |
+----------------------+
| multiline            |
| text                 |
| here                 |
+----------------------+
|                      |
+----------------------+
| some cells are empty |
+----------------------+
```

The function `counta` helps by counting nonempty cells, but it does not take into account multiple lines in the same cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by the following combination:

```
=counta(A2:A20) + sum(arrayformula(len(regexreplace(A2:A20, "[^\n]", ""))))
```

The first part, `counta`, counts each nonempty cell once. Then, `regexreplace` removes everything that is *not* a newline character `\n`. The `len` function then counts how many linebreaks the cell contains, and they are added up.

For the example above, there are 3 nonempty cells, and one of them contains 2 line breaks. So the formula returns 3 + 2 = 5.